# Jquery Change Tab Color on change Event

Tags: jquery, tabs

What I want to do is add a change event on controls and if that is fired, highlight that specific tab by changing the color of the background tab. I have no problem selecting the tab but it doesn't seem to want to change color. Here is the code I have, is anything off?

```
function SetChangeTabColor() {
    var $tabs = $('#tab').tabs();
    var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'active');
    selected.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: On line 3 do `$($tabs).tabs('option','active');` instead of `$tabs.tabs('option', 'active');`

Comment: that doesn't seem to have an effect